# virtualenv правильная инициализация проекта

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv

Подскажите правильно ли я все делаю в данный момент:

`-virtualenv -p python3 envname` (это у меня создаст окружение изолированное от других скачанных ранее библиотек)

`-git clone https://github.com/%%%/%%%` (я скопирую проект django в нем есть файл requirements.txt)

`-pip install -r requirements.txt` (я установлю зависимости)

все это будет работать? правильно я запускаю проект с env?

Comment: Добавь после клонирования репозитория команду cd  ```cd git_repo``` и потом уже pip install ...

Comment: Или клонируй ```git clone https://github.com/git_repo . ``` тогда репо в текущей директории будет и не нужно в него заходить.